# Blank window while running a game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, window, 2d-games

I'm using pygame for my game, but when I start it, I can see a black window. When you click on the close button, you can see all the objects of the game for a short while.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption('World of Fighters')

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('g_right1.png'),
pygame.image.load('g_right2.png'), pygame.image.load('g_right3.png'),
pygame.image.load('g_right4.png')]

walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('g_left1.png'),
pygame.image.load('g_left2.png'), pygame.image.load('g_left3.png'),
pygame.image.load('g_left4.png')]

bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
playerStand = pygame.image.load('g_stand.png')


clock = pygame.time.Clock()


#player 2
x2 = 720
y2 = 500

width2 = 35
height2 = 50
speed2 = 15

left2 = False
right2 = False
animCount2 = 0

isJump2 = False
jumpCount2 = 10


#player 1
x = 50
y = 500

width = 35
height = 50
speed = 15

left = False
right = False
animCount = 0

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

#blue
color = (0, 0, 255)

run = True

def drawWindow():
    global animCount
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    if animCount + 1 >= 30:
        animCount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[animCount // 5], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[animCount // 5], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(playerStand, (x, y))



    pygame.display.update() 

while run:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    #p1
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > 5:
        x -= speed
        left = True
        right = False   
    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 800 - width - 5:
        x += speed
        left = False
        right = True
    else:
        right = False
        left = False
        animCount = 0
    if not(isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            if jumpCount < 0:
                y += (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
            else:
                y -= (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
            jumpCount -= 1

        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10


    #p2
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x2 > 5:
        x2 -= speed2
        left2 = True
        right2 = False  
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x2 < 800 - width2 - 5:
        x2 += speed2
        left2 = False
        right2 = True
    if not(isJump2):

        if keys[pygame.K_RCTRL]:
            isJump2 = True
    else:
        right2 = False
        left2 = False
        animCount2 = 0
        if jumpCount2 >= -10:
            if jumpCount2 < 0:
                y2 += (jumpCount2 ** 2) / 2
            else:
                y2 -= (jumpCount2 ** 2) / 2
            jumpCount2 -= 1

        else:
            isJump2 = False
            jumpCount2 = 10

drawWindow()


pygame.quit()
```

Also, this game will be a dynamic fighter for 2 players in pixel art style, but I can't find the answer for this bug, because I watched a tutorial and I have the same code like on video.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). 
`drawWindow()` has to be called in the main application loop rather than after the loop.

What you do is:

> ```py
> while run:
>    clock.tick(30)
>    # [...]
>
> drawWindow()
>
> pygame.quit()
> ```

What you have to do is

```py
while run:
    clock.tick(30)
    # [...]

    drawWindow()

pygame.quit()
```